# How to make some code shown in bold font?

Tags: support, code-formatting

```
This is a **line** of code.
```

How can I make `line` and only **`line`** shown in bold font?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't and there is really no need to. 
If you want to "highlight" something in your code, point it out in a code comment.

Answer (score 3):

This cannot be done using markdown. Your only option is to resort to literal HTML:

```
<pre><code>This is a <strong>line</strong> of code.</code></pre>
```

Which renders as:

```
This is a line of code.
```

But this is ugly and hackish, and mostly unnecessary. [Do like Bart said](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/193179/153008) and use a comment to call out important things in your code samples instead.